# Virtualizing some domain controllers in a forest

Tags: active-directory, virtualization, hyper-v

our company has an AD forest made up of a root domain (domain ROOT) and two child domains (SUB1 and SUB2). The ROOT domain contains 2 DC's. SUB1 has 4 DC's and SUB2 has 3 DC's.  Currently all the DC's are physical servers.

Currently we are planning to do a hardware upgrade and I was investigating the possibility of virtualizing (Hyper-v) some of the domain controllers. These domain controllers are critical to the company and our management is a bit wary to virtualize the whole infrastructure - and probably would only accept if I virtualize just 1 DC in each domain.

In this regard, can you help me choose which DC's to virtualize? Do you have any suggestions as to what FSMO roles/GC I should virtualize (if any)? Also do you have any arguments I could put forward to support the idea of virtualizing the DC (maybe easier to backup/restore, possibility to perform live migrations??) ?

I am still in my early days on windows side (coming from a linux side ;) so thanks for bearing with me!

Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: Virtualizing your Domain Controllers is fully supported by Microsoft. This article is related to W2K8 and W2K8R2, but Microsoft's position on this carries forward to W2K12 and W2K12R2 - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/virtual_active_directory_domain_controller_virtualization_hyperv(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Are there any suggestions as to what FSMO roles or GC should NOT be virtualised?

Comment: All FSMO roles and Global Catalog servers can be virtualized and are fully supported by Microsoft.